# Calculating several averages from a single Vegas Monte Carlo grid

Tags: c, gsl, montecarlo, numerical-integration

I'm using the Vegas (importance sampling) Monte Carlo method implemented in the `gsl` library to evaluate various integrals of the form `I_i = int f(x) g_i(x) dx`, with different `g_i` but the same `f > 0`. In particular, one of the `g_i`, say `g_0` is identically `1`, so its corresponding integral is simply that of `f`. One can think of the other `I_i` as the mean of `g_i` under the `f` distribution, more explicitly:

```
I_i/I_0 = (int f(x) g_i(x) dx)/(int f(x) dx) = <g_i>_f
```

Since the idea behind importance sampling is to sample the integrand accordingly to its absolute value, I wonder whether it is possible (and valid) to take advantage of the already-optimized grid obtained after integrating `f` and sample all the `g_i` from that distribution, by setting the option `stage=3` and changing the integrand in the call to `gsl_monte_vegas_integrate`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing notation! I checked the "editing-help" page, but found no LaTeX-like commands to write down the integral, so I put "int" without thinking of the data type. Also, the angle brackets "< >" are used to express an average.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you want: Do you want to sample a function, say g_0, by letting VEGAS adapt the grid and then sample other functions with that same grid? That should work, I don't see a reason why it should not. If the functions are similar this also makes sense. But be careful: The grid function f(x) is already properly normalized, i.e. I_0 = 1.